# Artisan::call method in Laravel is not working

Tags: laravel

I created a button for the user to be able to clear cache routes and views.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="{{route('cache.clear')}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">clear cache</a>
</div>
```

I'm using  `Artisan::call` but it does not work. Where is my problem?

```
Route::get('/clearcache', function() {
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');

    return show_message(true, 'clear cache  ');
})->name('cache.clear');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what "is not working"?

Comment: @lagbox thanks , non of my views or routes does not clear after I click on this button ,also the massage has shown ,I don't know why ?

Comment: how are you determining that that is the case? that the compiled views and the cached route file are gone

Comment: Are you getting an error? How are you verifying that the statement is not working?

Comment: @lagbox  my views save in the storage , and if a run php artisan view:clear ,all become clear .

Comment: after I click on this button ,also the massage has shown ,but  non of my views or routes does not clear and there is no error

Comment: @melissapoorkamaly how do you sure _non of my views or routes does not clear_ ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the `show_message()` function, your code works.

```
Route::get('/clearcache', function() {
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
})->name('cache.clear');
```

Change the route, run `php artisan serve`. Then hit the route directly in your browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/clearcache

Another option...

```
php artisan optimize:clear

Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
```

This will return you the following.

```
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
```

All cache types that exist in your Laravel application will be cleared entirely, except Events cache.